# Adding and ".indexOn": ".value" into Firebase Rules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm studying AngularJS and Firebase and I'm playing with a simple ChatApp, just to understand the code.

My Firebase DB structure is like this:

```
"chat": {
    "messages": {
        "chat1": { [ list of messages ] },
        "chat2": { [ list of messages ] }
    },
    "rooms": {
        "chat1": {
            "users": {
                "user1": true,
                "user2": true
            }
        },
        "chat2": {
            "users": {
                "user2": true,
                "user3": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Due to Firebase protection Rules I can't add chat link in the user node, than I necessary have to do a Firebase query to retrieve chat rooms for user, using `orderByChild()` query on App Start Up.

Using Firebase is simple than I can retrieve all chat using:

```
var chatLink = firebase.database().ref('chat/rooms');
chatLink
  .orderByChild('users/' + userId)
  .equalTo(true)
  .once('value', function(chatSnap){

      /* Do Some Stuff Here */

  });
```

Every thing work well, but I'm receiving a warning in the console:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "users/{userId}" at /chat/rooms to your security rules for better performance

Searching on the web, I found that for variable `orderByChild()` query, I can user `.indexOn: .value` in my Firebase Rules.

I've tried to add this Rule:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "chat": {
            "rooms": {
                ".indexOn": ".value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm still receive always that warning. How can i fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You say you've "had to add this rule":
```{
    "rules": {
        "chat": {
            "rooms": {
                ".indexOn": ".value"
            }
        }
    }
}```
But where and how are you adding it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To index this structure to allow efficient querying, you have to add an index for each user:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "chat": {
            "rooms": {
                ".indexOn": ["users/user1", "users/user2"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That won't be maintainable, since you're likely adding users dynamically.

As usual with NoSQL databases, this means you have to expand/adapt your data model to allow the use-case you want. Instead of querying the rooms for their users, keep a list of the rooms for each user (in addition to your current data):

```
"user_rooms": {
  "user1": {
    "chat1": true
  },
  "user2": {
    "chat1": true,
    "chat2": true
  }
  "user3": {
    "chat2": true
  }
```

Now you can look up the chat rooms for a user without even needing to query.

Also see my answer about this categorization problem in [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value).

Comment: Thanks, but what about rules like ".indexOn": ".value"? I've read that i can use it with variable query, but seems not working in my case...

Comment: An index on `.value` will work for `orderByValue` queries. Yours is an `orderByChild` query, so it needs an index on each named child.

Comment: If I wanted to query to find all the users in a chat room using this model, wouldn't we still run into the problem of the missing ".indexOn" value?

Answer (score 17):

I am aware that this may be a bit too late but here is something that may help you. I was looking for the same information as you, and in my case, it helped me.

`$usersId` matches any child key. So you have to do something like this.

```
{
"rules": {
      "chat": {
          "rooms": {
              "users": {
                  "$usersId": {
                    ".indexOn": ".value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My case:

Using an unspecified index. Consider adding `".indexOn": "date"` at `messages/-L2bPVX4_fL41H7lhexc` to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance:

`L2bPVX4_fL41H7lhexc == child` in my NoSQL database structure

solution:

```
"messages": {
  "$messagesId": {
    ".indexOn": "date"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Later i will check if your solutions may work in my database rules!

Comment: Let me know if it helped you :)

Comment: "users": {
                 "$usersId": {
                    ".indexOn": ".value"
                }
            } . never works. why?

Comment: It depends on your database structure what you'll have to write. In my post i wrote what i had to add in my DB and what OP should do. I don't know what is your db structure.

Comment: @HanWhiteking, try "users": { ".indexOn": ".value"  }