# Firebase Realtime Database EqualTo Index Rules Xamarin Forms

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, firebase-security

I'm doing a Xamarin Forms multiplatform app on Visual Studio.
I work with Firebase Realtime Database and I created a nested table like that

[image]

I need to do create a listview where I can see every Book the user read filtered by genre.

```
return (await firebase
              .Child("Utenti")
              .Child(ID)
              .Child("Books")
              .OrderBy("Genere")
              .EqualTo("Gialli")
              .OnceAsync<Utente>()).Select(item => new Utente
              {

              }).ToList();
```

The problem is I have to update the rules of realtime database and add indexOn Genere to use EqualTo. But ID always changes, because it is user's UID.

I tried with

```
"Utenti": {
".indexOn": ["Genere"] }
```

But the App crashes and ask me to use the entire root. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260689/adding-and-indexon-value-into-firebase-rules) to see if it helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

An index (and its query) are defined at a specific location, and then index (and order by) a value that is at a specific path under each child node. The child nodes of your `Utenti` don't have a `Genere` property, so the index will be empty.

To index the property in the JSON screenshot, you need an index like this:

```
"Utenti": {
  ".indexOn": ["Books/codice0/Genere"] 
}
```

With this definition each child node of `Utenti` will be in the index by the value of its `Books/codice0/Genere` property. This also immediately means that you can only have one value of `Utenti`, so you can't search across multiple books.

If you want to search across all `Utenti` across all books, you'll need to create a flat list of all books in your data structure. You'd then associate a book with a `Utenti` by storing the `Utenti`'s key as a property in the book.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Problem is, codice0 always changes, just like the user's ID. I'm going to store book's key as a property of the user but I got problems with getting data so I'm just making attempts now, thank you by the way!